# How to apply Domain GPO to local Work group Server

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, workgroup

I need to export all the settings in Domain GPO and need to import in local work group Server . 
I have seen many sites but there were only local settings import, but I need to import all setting including administrative template, windows setting, software setting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI Jim i tried Localgpo but dont know how to use it ..if i export one policy from domain and run it on workgroup server .does this will replace the policies which are already defined in work group server ?

Comment: Hi, welcome on SF, be sure to comment on @JimB answer to get a response, or tag him, else we dont get notified of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the localgpo tool from the security and compliance manager to export the settings from a domain joined machine to the work group one.

Comment: HI Jim i tried Localgpo but dont know how to use it ..if i export one policy from domain and run it on workgroup server .does this will replace the policies which are already defined in work group server ?

Comment: A PDF document comes with the download on how to use the tool.  Yes if there is a conflict the policy you manually applied will overwrite anything previously on that setting.